# How do I install mods for Kerbal Space Program 1.1?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

How do I install mods into the latest 1.1 version of KSP? I tried to put the .zip file into the *gamedata* folder but when I launched I didn't see the parts.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put the *unzipped* contents of the mod in the right location which is more often than not `GameData`.

Here is a screenshot of my install with the base Squad game data, along with 2 mods

[image]